# How to update an aggregate table in a trigger procedure while taking care of proper concurrency?

Tags: postgresql

For illustration, say I'm updating a table ProductOffers and their prices. Mutations to this table are of the form: add new ProductOffer, change price of existing ProductOffer.

Based on the above changes, I'd like to update a Product-table which holds pricing info per product aggregated over all offers.

It seems logical to implement this using a row-based update/insert trigger, where the trigger runs a procedure creating/updating a Product row.

I'd like to properly implement concurrent updates (and thus triggers). I.e.: updating productOffers of the same Product concurrently, would potentially lead to wrong aggregate values (because multiple triggered procedures would concurrently attempt to insert/update the same Product-row)

It seems I cannot use row-based locking on the product-table (i.e.: `select .. for update`) because it's not guaranteed that a particular product-row already exists. Instead the first time around a Product row must be created (instead of updated) once a ProductOffer triggers the procedure. Afaik, row-locking can't work with new rows to be inserted, which totally makes sense.

So where does that leave me? Would I need to roll my own optimistic locking scheme? This would need to include:

- check row not exists => create new row fail if already exists. (which is possible if 2 triggers concurrently try to create a row). Try again afterwards, with an update.
- check row exists and has version=x => update row but fail if row.version !=x. Try again afterwards

Would the above work, or any better / more out-of-the-box solutions?

**EDIT**:

For future ref: found official example which exactly illustrates what I want to accomplish: [Example 39-6. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Procedure For Maintaining A Summary Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: Short answer: one of a several available locks (table locks, etc)

Comment: yeah, so since row-level locks seems out of the question, I'd need to have full blown table locks? This would dramatically impact performance right. Looking for getting approx 500 updates/sec on this table, which seems undoable when using table-locks?

Comment: First off, you don't need to "roll your own" locking scheme using columns (like version, etc). 
If your aggregate rows are by "product" and only need to consider other items in the same Product, you can use an advisory lock to let other transactions know that a particular product is currently being recalculated-- and then have your app make sure a product is not locked before adding more rows. This will slow things down on a per product rather than a per table basis which may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are much simpler than you think they are, thanks to the I an [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

The trigger you envision will run in the same transaction as the data modification that triggered it, and each modification to the aggregate table will first lock the row that it wants to update with an `EXCLUSIVE` lock.

So if two concurrent transactions cause an `UPDATE` on the same row in the aggregate table, the first transaction will get the lock and proceed, while the second transaction will have to wait until the first transaction commits (or rolls back) before it can get the lock on the row and modify it.

So data modifications that update the same row in the aggregate table will effectively be serialized, which may hurt performance, but guarantees exact results.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but what if the row does not yet exist and two triggers will attempt to create a row for the same product?

Comment: Create a unique constraint that forbids two rows for the same product and use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... UPDATE`.