# Are increments with Postgres triggers atomic and high concurrency safe?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Given the following setup:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
  id TEXT DEFAULT gen_random_uuid () NOT NULL,
  text TEXT NOT NULL,
  is_latest BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
  version INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_id_idx ON foo (id, is_latest);
CREATE INDEX foo_updated_at_idx ON foo (updated_at);
CREATE INDEX foo_created_at_idx ON foo (created_at);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_copy_row ()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  NEW.version = OLD.version + 1;
  NEW.is_latest = TRUE;
  NEW.updated_at = NOW();
  NEW.created_at = OLD.created_at;
  INSERT INTO foo (id, text, is_latest, version, updated_at, created_at)
  VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.text, NULL, OLD.version, OLD.updated_at, OLD.created_at);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER COPY BEFORE
UPDATE
  ON foo FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_copy_row ();
```

I am able to successfully version my data, and on every update atomically increment the `version` column.

My problem is that when I have high concurrency updates on the same row I am expecting `ORDER BY id, version DESC` and `ORDER BY id, updated_at DESC` to be identical but they are not.

This is how I update my rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo (text) VALUES ('hello')
RETURNING *;

UPDATE foo SET text = 'welcome'
WHERE id = 'some-uuid' AND is_latest = TRUE
RETURNING *;
```

And this is an example of result:

```
SELECT id, is_latest, version, updated_at, created_at FROM foo ORDER BY id, updated_at DESC;
```

-

```
                 id                  | is_latest | version |          updated_at           |          created_at
-------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
4d2339ba-eb1f-4925-a4bc-753f2994bd5f | t         |       4 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.702035+00 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.694725+00
4d2339ba-eb1f-4925-a4bc-753f2994bd5f |           |       2 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.698144+00 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.694725+00
4d2339ba-eb1f-4925-a4bc-753f2994bd5f |           |       1 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.697429+00 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.694725+00
4d2339ba-eb1f-4925-a4bc-753f2994bd5f |           |       3 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.697157+00 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.694725+00
4d2339ba-eb1f-4925-a4bc-753f2994bd5f |           |       0 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.694725+00 | 2018-07-22 16:12:55.694725+00
```

What's the missing piece?

Is the trigger part of the transaction and is the UPDATE lock retained until both BEFORE and AFTER are executed?

Is it possible to end up with two rows with same id and version number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not surprising. `now()` returns the time when the transaction started. There is no guarantee that the transaction that starts first will be the first one to perform the trigger.

Use the version to determine the order of the updates.

Comment: That's alarming. I thought UPDATE had a lock on the row. I can easily fix this doing `version = version + 1` in my update statement. What do you think?

Comment: Also, how would you go about forcing this behavior so that I can add it to my test suite?

Comment: @laurez-albe I found your comment in another post that, at first (and second) glance seems in contradiction with what you say here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790324/how-to-update-an-aggregate-table-in-a-trigger-procedure-while-taking-care-of-pro

Comment: On second glance I'd say that you are right and two concurrent updates cannot end up with the same `version` because the rows will be locked *before* the trigger runs. I'll remove that paragraph; sorry for the false alarm.